# Change Informatica Cloud User for Secure Agent

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud

We have a scenario where a secure agent is installed on an ms server environment with a specific Informatica cloud user. 
Now we would like to change the user which is being used by the secure agent. What would be the procedure to change username and password to another Informatica cloud user. Are there any precautions to assure like visibility and rights?

Comment: You may also try posting your Informatica question on their forum: https://network.informatica.com/community/informatica-network/products/cloud-integration/cloud-application-integration/

Answer (score 0):

I have doubts about your question, but from what I understand you want to change the agent owner, right?

To change the owner of the secure agent

for windows:

[Change user agent secure - for windows](https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/509723?language=en_US&type=external)

for linux:

[Change user agent secure - for linux](https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/510083?language=en_US&type=external)

Or in the last case you can delete the secure agent folder and perform a new installation.